# Can't Access Network Drive On Ethernet-Shared PC

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, ethernet, network-shares

I am unable to access the network drive I have set up on my Ubuntu PC (ubu) from any device on the network, and I believe it's due to the fact that I am using windows ethernet-share from my primary Windows PC (win).

My router only has 2 ethernet ports on it, both of which are in use, and only one of which I have control over. I am sharing ethernet from win to ubu because ubu does not have a wireless card, the two PCs are sitting right next to each other, and they are both out of wifi range regardless.

win has a local ip of 10.0.0.240 and ubu has a local ip of 192.168.137.10, and I'm wondering if my devices are having trouble finding the network drive because it's "on another network".

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to connect to the network drive though win as a router or something, and my apologies, I'm not very well versed in networking. Or any advice on how to reconfigure my windows ethernet share so the network drive can be accessed from outside.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long term, you would be wise to buy a small Gigabit Ethernet switch (available for US$20 or less) to plug into your router's Ethernet LAN port that you have control over, and plug both of your PCs into that switch. That way your Ubuntu PC's network-shared drive will still be available even when the Windows PC is down for any reason.

Short term, on your Windows PC, you should switch from using Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) to just bridging its two Ethernet interfaces together. Bridging between Ethernet interfaces allows traffic to pass through transparently, just like a switch, making both sides of the Windows PC be part of the same Ethernet LAN, the same broadcast/multicast domain, and the same IP subnet, which allows LAN-based discovery protocols to work. In contrast, ICS creates a NAT, which effectively blocks discovery protocols and mostly blocks devices on the "upstream/public/WAN" side of the NAT from initiating connections to devices on the "downstream/private/LAN" side of the NAT.

In Windows, you should be able to bridge your two Ethernet interfaces together by going into Network Connections, selecting them both, right-clicking and selecting "Bridge Connections".

Bridging two Ethernet interfaces on Windows may have other affects on your Windows networking configuration, so it's good to read up on the process before jumping in. That's beyond the scope of this answer, but here's an article you may find helpful to get you started: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-and-manage-network-bridge-connection-windows-10

Comment: So this did solve the immediate issue, the bridge did work, however it sprung up a bunch of other problems for me, which I was able to widdle away one by one. The bridge did point me in the right direction.